# layout-align not working in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have this code , here when screen size is more than **small** layout-align is working well but when it is smaller than **Small** layout align is not working

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row" layout-lt-sm="column" flex layout-align="space-around center">

    <!-- main content like jokes and news will go here -->
    <div flex-gt-sm="55" flex="80">
        <md-card class="md-whiteframe-5dp">
            hello</md-card>

    </div>
    <!-- todo and upcoming event will go here -->
    <div flex-gt-sm="35" flex="80">
        <div>
            <ng-include src="'templates/dashboard/todo.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ng-include src="'templates/dashboard/todo.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Material no longer offers the `layout-lt-*` directives. Instead, you should just do:

```
<div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row">
```

This is likely causing your layout align directives to not work because they do not currently have a parent layout in your code.

You can read a bit more here: https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/layout/container